# Override value of field in type annotation, when this annotation is part of other annotation in java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Lets assume I have following annotation types:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TypeA {   
    TypeB[] arrayOfTypeB();
}

public @interface TypeB {
    String firstField();
    String secondField();
}
```

And a class that uses these annotation types:

```
@TypeA(arrayOfTypeB = {
        @TypeB(
                firstField = "first field",
                secondField = "second field"),
})
public class ClassUsingTheseTypes{
}
```

How to change secondFIeld value using reflection in Java?

Comment: Annotation values are not fields, regardless of whether you name them “fields”. If you want to have fields, just use fields.

Comment: @Holger I can't, I'm paraphrasing here an example i have to deal with to change value of annotation field of external package my company is using, but of course it comes with different name than secondField

Comment: You are using the term “annotation field” again. Annotations have no fields. Annotations are constant information. From the Java language point of view, they are *modifiers*, just like `final`, `abstract`, or `strictfp`. You can’t change a class’ modifiers at runtime. There is no support for changing annotations in Reflection. When you search this site, you might find some deep, nasty hacks that may make the reflective data look like you’ve changed an annotation. These hacks are fragile, non-portable, and subject to break when updating your Java environment.Focus on your actual problem instead